# AngularJS - Call Directive from Controller on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services, stomp

**HTML**

```
<li>            
 <a ng-href ng-click="startStreaming(camera);">{{camera.name}}<i class="fa fa-tv"></i></a>
</li>

<object events="True" id="vlc" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" 
classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921">
<embed width="800" height="650" loop="no" autoplay="yes" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" 
type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" id="vlc" embed-src="" src="">
</object>
```

**Ctrl**

```
cameraModule.controller('streamingCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'cameraModuleServiceAPI', '$timeout', 'svc', '$q', 'sharedService','mySharedService',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, cameraModuleServiceAPI, $timeout, svc, $q, sharedService, mySharedService) {
    var rtspobj = null;
    $scope.startStreaming = function (data) {

        // Request Start Streaming
        var jason_start_streme = { "START_STREAMER_REQUEST": { "command ": 1, "cameraID": 123, "streamingMedium": 0 } };
        cameraModuleServiceAPI.start_streme(jason_start_streme).then(function (data) {

        $rootScope.$watch(svc.getMessage, function (v) {
            $timeout(function () {
                if (v != '') {

                    rtspobj = angular.fromJson(v.content);
                    $rootScope.cameraRTSPUrl = rtspobj.START_STREAMER_RESPONSE.RtspURL;
                    console.log("Camera Click : " + $rootScope.cameraRTSPUrl);
                    sharedService.prepForBroadcast($rootScope.cameraRTSPUrl);    
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        });
};
```

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('embedSrc', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var current = element;
            scope.$watch(attrs.embedSrc, function () {                
                var clone = element.clone().attr('src', scope.cameraRTSPUrl);
                current.replaceWith(clone);
                current = clone;
            });

        }
    };
});
```

**Requirement:**

When function `startStreaming` is called, video url will be fetched in controller and only then directive will be called which will change the 
`embed` src and play the video.

How can I call my directive only when startStreaming is clicked, passing the video url from controller to directive and eventually changing embed src ?

Comment: You need to watch `$rootScope.cameraRTSPUrl` instead of `attrs.embedSrc` in your `embedSrc` directive.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH, tried changing directive to `scope.$watch(attrs.embedSrc, function () {
                scope.$watch(svc.getMessage, function (v) {` but not sure if $watch can be used multiple times. Suggestions please